# Possible to define column types and sizes for a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-view

I'm making a view to make my life easier when importing some data through C#, and it would be a huge time saver if I could do all the conversions and casting (and setting correct column lengths) on the SQL side and not in C# (because my C# code is all dynamic, not hard coded and it's falling over when stuff is not the correct length). This is more or less what I'm doing on a very small scale:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_pendingitems
AS
   SELECT 
      CAST(a.columnone AS CHAR(1)) 'Column 1', 
      CAST(a.columntwo AS CHAR(1)) 'Column 2', 
      CAST(a.adecimalcolumn AS VARCHAR(30)), 
      CAST(null AS VARCHAR(20)) 'A not yet defined column',
      b.anintcolumn 'An int column'
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.key = b.key
```

The first two columns are working fine, but I think I'm hitting issues when I cast a null. Are there any other/better ways of doing what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: r u missing a closing ) for the 3rd column?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that :)

Comment: @LoganDam : What would you prefer to happen if null is encountered in `a.adecimalcolumn`? What error are you getting presently ?

Comment: `a.adecimalcolumn` will never have a null value, the table I'm fetching from has that column set to `not null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CAST` should work fine with a nullable column. It will just return `NULL`. If you do not want `NULL` then you can use `ISNULL`.

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)), '') 'A not yet defined column'
```

You should be careful with changing the data types though. If you use smaller data types you could either lose data or get an error.

Comment: It is working fine now. I was getting an error I though was related to the nulls, turns out I was just trying to turn a string like 'NAD' into an int which dies obviously. I'm not worried about data loss either, it has to happen in my case.